# How to change my schema for each request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, npgsql

I would like to change my schema dynamically depending the HTTP Request based on the UserID. I know that the OnModelCreating is just started one time and i try the DB Interceptor with Npgsql but no sucsess !
I have a specific schema by user and i would like to read and write some data inside.
Techno: Asp.Net 4.5

Thank you

Comment: I think you want an unstructured data store, why not look at noSql databases like RavenDb or Mongo ?

Comment: Good answer but my requirement is to use PostgreSQL database

Comment: `I would like to change my schema dynamically` Can you please give an example? Also, why can't you have a JSONB column and store json documents? or, say, use Marten?

Comment: For example, we have multiples schema (ABC_USERID...) in PG and each schema is just for one client. With HTTP Context, i know the userid of requester. I would like to pass the userID to the DB Context for each http request

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL, the schema that is search/defaulted can be set on the ConnectionString. The parameter is called "Search Path". More information can be found [here](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html).

So if you have control over the connectionstring before connecting you can add the parameter ;Search Path=ABC_USERID,public. This says that look to ABC_USERID schema and if it doesn't find it then search in public schema

As long as you don't qualify the table name with a schema it will for the objects in your search path.

-HTH